# Comma between components of adverbial clause connected by a coordinating conjunctions

Tags: grammar, commas, conjunctions, adverbials, dependent-clause

When you have an adverbial clause that contains two complete clauses within it connected by a coordinating conjunction, should you add a comma before the conjunction? For example:

> Because my arm was broken(,) and it would not get better any soon, I had to sit out of the game.

> While I hated broccoli(,) and my sister hated it too, we were forced to eat it every day when growing up.

Would adding those commas be correct, or are the sentences better without them? I typically leave them out, as the subordinating conjunction seems to govern both parts while keeping them in one dependent clause; inserting a comma would indicate that the second is an independent clause when, in reality, it doesn't work on its own.

I have read that you would add a comma if the subordinating conjunction were repeated, as in

> Because my arm was broken, and because it would not get better any soon, I had to sit out of the game,

But I have not been able to find any concrete rules for what to do when there is only one subordinator. Does any such rule exist? Or is this ultimately just a stylistic choice?

Comment: A fan of commas, I'd say both your examples want to hold the first two clauses together to set up the final one. So, no comma there helps your point: Because of A and B, C. While X and Y, Z.

Comment: An adverbial clause is not an independent clause nor does it contain one. So no commas are “required.”

Comment: The commas would be appropriate if you considered those clauses to be parenthetical, not essential. You could also set it off with hyphens or parentheses in that case.